# How to create the directory in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mkdir

I struggle to create a directory in my Dockerfile below. Entering the container after building the image I can't find the directory "models". "ds" directory in path "/usr/src/app/ds/models" is an application directory which was copied. Could you please tell me what is wrong here.

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV DISPLAY :0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/ds/models
```

My docker-compose.yaml file contains volume:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

Comment: You can't find `/usr/src/app/test`?

Comment: if during the build no error is thrown, `/usr/src/app/test` should be there

Comment: Alberto, there are no errors, but after copying folders of my app I can't create a subfolder, in the running container it doesn't exist

Comment: Can you just give the whole docker-compose as well

Comment: @RyanSchaefer, I have added more information about docker-compose file above.

Comment: You're mapping your current directory into /usr/src/app which hides the directory you made.

Comment: @Hans, i need to download models to this directory, but i don't know should i create it locally and then copy because models directory is just a subfolder in one of the app directory with files which i copy.

Answer (score 1):

When your `docker-compose.yml` file says

```yaml
volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/app
```

that host directory completely replaces the `/usr/src/app` directory from your image.  This means pretty much nothing in your Dockerfile has an effect; if you try to deploy this setup to another system, you've never run the code in the image.

I'd recommend deleting this block, and also the `command:` override (make it be the default `CMD` in the Dockerfile instead).

> I need to download models to this directory

Mount only the specific directory you need into your container; don't overwrite the entire application tree.  Potentially consider keeping that data directory in a different part of the filesystem.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    # no command:
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # only the models subdirectory, not the entire application
      - ./ds/models:/usr/src/app/ds/models
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please refactor my Dockerfile according to the docker-compose file. Seems i have to create the directory locally "./ds/models:" in Dockerfile

Comment: `WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/ds/models
COPY . .
`
So, I have to create a subfolder first and then copy other app folders?

Comment: The `./ds/models` directory is on your host system.  The `volumes:` declaration will create both that directory and the `/usr/src/app/ds/models` inside the container, if either or both doesn't exist yet.  The only change you should need to make to the Dockerfile is to end it with `CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one thing we need to note here is Docker build always use Shell to connect and execute commands into the container during the docker build process i observe issues while i was trying to run bash compatible commands like if you wanted to create directories in bash compatible way

```
RUN mkdir -p /yourpath/{dir1,dir2,dir3/dir1}
```

Above command will create a single directory with name

```
{dir1,dir2,dir3/dir1
```

IF objective is to create multiple directories in single command so its bash compatible command shell won't support such way in order to run bash compatible commands in docker build you might need to add like below

```
RUN bash -c 'mkdir -p /yourpath/{dir1,dir2,dir3/dir1}'
```

Above will create three directories.

**Conclusion**
To run Bash compatible commands in Docker build add **bash -c** in your RUN command